# Unexpected 2D array position?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm creating a battleship type game and I need to read from a text file to initially set the board. I'm converting the character letters to integers so i can think about the entire board as a 2D integer array.

When  B 4 is read in, the B gets converted to a 1 and the char 'S' should be set at gamePieces[1][4]

My two cout statements posted below equate to 1 and 4 when i print them but
when I drop those same exact statements inside my gameBoard pieces brackets [][] it lands in a spot in the array spot gamePieces[6][2]?

I'm planning to use my for loop to go through the rest of the input file lines after i get the logic correct.

The text file being read looks like:

5

B 4

C 9

E 7

D 3

J 4

```
string input;
        vector<string> shipPosistions;
        while (getline(shipdata, input)) {
            cout << input << endl;
            shipPosistions.push_back(input);
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < shipPosistions.size(); i++) {
            gamePieces[(int) shipPosistions[1][0] - 65 ] [shipPosistions[1][2]] = 'S';
            

        }
            cout << (int) shipPosistions[1][0] - 65 << endl; // this line prints 1
            cout << shipPosistions[1][2] << endl;           // this line prints 4
        
    }

My output....
1
4

    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  |---------------------|
A | o o o o o o o o o o |
B | o o o o o o o o o o |
C | o o o o o o o o o o |
D | o o o o o o o o o o |
E | o o o o o o o o o o |
F | o o o o o o o o o o |
G | o o S o o o o o o o |
H | o o o o o o o o o o |
I | o o o o o o o o o o |
J | o o o o o o o o o o |
  |---------------------|

Expected output.....
1
4

    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  |---------------------|
A | o o o o o o o o o o |
B | o o o o S o o o o o |
C | o o o o o o o o o o |
D | o o o o o o o o o o |
E | o o o o o o o o o o |
F | o o o o o o o o o o |
G | o o o o o o o o o o |
H | o o o o o o o o o o |
I | o o o o o o o o o o |
J | o o o o o o o o o o |
  |---------------------|
```

Comment: Try `[shipPosistions[1][2] - '0'] = 'S';`

Comment: Ah yes! That worked. Thank you.

Comment: You also probably want `i` in there instead of `1`.

Comment: Remember, in C/C++ everything you read is a character -- until you provide a conversion to make it something else...